# JWT authorizer for plaid webhook

Tags: aws-api-gateway, webhooks, plaid

How to verify plaid webhook at the aws-api-gateway. Does plaid has reference implementation document to create JWT authorizer at AWS to verify plaid webhook?

Answer (score 1):

They do provide documentation on validating the JWT that they send on the webhook requests. https://plaid.com/docs/api/webhooks/webhook-verification/

I believe you can implement this on an API GW Lambda Authorizer and add the authorizer to our API GW resource(s).

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on Kunal's answer.

You'll want to use `python-jose` to validate their JWT. I wish Plaid's docs were a bit more verbose and thorough with this requirement. Using PyJWT; you'll have a bad time.

To fully verify, 1:1 per their example, you'll want to configure a new AWS APIG Custom Authorizer Lambda that's configured to receive the full request, not just the JWT. IE: `REQUEST input format`
Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-input.html

This will allow the Lambda (Custom Authorizer) to verify the JWT and the body (payload) of the request against the signed SHA256 hash.